# How to put generic view code in a Django base template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a simple Django site with a base template and then various templates for specific pages. This works for well for applying branding, styles etc.

My site is conceptually similar to something like JIRA, where every view needs to be informed by an overarching variable called project, which the user can select from a dropdown in the menu bar.

The menu bar is in the base template. The dropdown will be populated by a database query (get all the projects the logged in user is associated with). How can I do that query and send the data to the base template? I'd rather not attach the same query to every view that uses the template!

Comment: Is this a job for a template tag, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided to use template tags. Here's how to do it:

1. Under the relevant app folder, create a `templatetags/` folder.
2. Inside the `templatetags` folder, create an empty file called `__init__.py`
3. Inside the `templatetags` folder, create a file for your tag. We'll call it `menu_items.py`
4. This will be an inclusion tag, which means it'll need a template file as well. Set it up like this:

   ```
   from django import template
   from relevant_app import ItemToDisplay

   register = template.Library()

   @register.inclusion_tag('relevant_app/menu_items.html', takes_context=True)
   def menu_items(context):
       return {'items': ItemsToDisplay.objects.all()}
   ```
5. Create the `menu_items.html` template file inside the relevant template folder (in this case, in the `relevant_app` project, it would be `templates\relevant_app`):

   ```
   {% for item in items %}
       <li><a href="{% url items item=item %}">{{ item.item_name }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
   ```
6. Add the template tag to the main template:

   ```
   {% load menu_items %}
   {# ... #}
   {% menu_items %}
   ```

This seems to be the Django way to do this. Tag types seem a bit fiddly though; I struggled getting them all to accept the context so I only use `inclusion_tag` for now.

Answer (score 1):

Here lately, I've been storing queries that are called on every page in middleware objects and storing the response in the request object.

For example

```
# Advanced Queries 
from django.db.models import Q # If you need if ( not required ) 
from django.conf        import settings     # Application Configuration

class NameThisClass(object):

     def process_request(self, request):
         """
         Do some processing to get information from the url to load the correct project information.
         """
         request.projects = {}
         request.projects["menu"] = Menu.objects.filter(params)
```

You can then get access to it in every template, and call without having to pass it from
the module view.

Like So

```
{{ request.menu }}
```

Note: This would be just like running your traditional for loop of the objects if required.

You will have to discover away to get the correct information from the URL but
that is really trivial in some cases.

**Notes:** 
Make sure you have setup context processors in your settings.py file.
As well as add the middleware location in your middleware dict in your settings.py

All the best